# Compiling Assembly Script in External EEPROM to Arduino Code

Tags: arduino-nano, eeprom

I'm working on a simple game console, and I'm planning to use a cartridge system using an EEPROM. I know that you can read and write data from an EEPROM, but can you compile the data into executable Arduino code, and vice versa? If the Arduino can do it, we can probably too, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no such thing as "arduino code" when the microcontroller executes it

Comment: have a look at `forth` programming language

Comment: @jsotola so is there some sort of compiler that turns arduino code into EEPROM code, and vice versa?

Comment: the microcontroller executes machine code ... in simple terms, the machine code is generated by the C++ compiler and loaded into the arduino ... the reason that i suggested forth is because forth is an interpretter that runs on the arduino ... it could possibly execute code originating from an EEPROM

Comment: @jsotola I see. I would use that, but I am using libraries to control the screen. I doubt that be converted into Forth, so that's my issue. I suppose I could control the screen manually, but it seems like a lot of work.

Comment: yes it would be a learning curve ... you did not describe your project, so it was unclear what component would need to be controlled

Comment: My project is basically a joystick connected to an LCD screen. So far I've just gotten a square to move around.

Here is the LCD screen I am using:

[LCD Screen](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you investigate a different micro with external addressing or one that loads its code from an external memory such as flash like the ESP32s do.